# fetching data causing empty form for a sec [using react-query with react-hook-forms]

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-query

I'm creating a SPA todo app,
and I'm using `react-hooks-forms` for creating and editing the todo, and `react-query` for fetching the todo.

When the user clicks 'save' - the pathname is changed from create-todo to `todo/:id` and invalidates the current `useGetTodo` query, when the path changes `useGetTodo` fetches the todo from the server.

The problem is - after changing the path and re-fetching the todo - the form is empty for a second and refills after `useGetTodo` finishes fetching the todo (which is the todo I created before clicking save, the fields are the same, and nothing should change)

this is the form init

```
  const {todo} = useGetTodo();


  const getDefaultValues = useCallback(() => {
    return { name: todo.name, isDone: todo.isDone } 
  }, [todo]);

  const form = useForm({
    mode: 'all',
    defaultValues: useMemo(getDefaultValues, [getDefaultValues]),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (todo) {
      reset(getDefaultValues);
    }
  }, [reset, todo, getDefaultValues]);
```

this is the react-query for useGetTodo:

```
  const {data, ...rest} = useQuery(['todo', todoId], async () => {
    if (todoId) {
      return await getTodo(todoId)
    }
    return null;
  })
```

and this is the react-query init

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    suspense: false,
    keepPreviousData: true,
  }
})
```

and when the user clicks save I'm invalidating the query,
getting the updated todo from the server and reseting the form with

```
  const todoMutation = useMutation(
    ['todo'],
    getUpdatedTodo,
    {onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(['todo', todoId])}
  );
```

Is there anything that could cause this issue?

Comment: please check if your queryClient is referentially stable: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#2-the-queryclient-is-not-stable

Comment: moved it outside of the app and it still happening for some reason